# How to move static block in magento 2.1.8 at the bottom of product list in Category

Tags: php, css, magento, magento2

I am using MAgento 2.1.8 but i am stuck in moving static block to bottom of product list of a category page as i want to write the content 
Before and after to products.

Comment: Do you want to show block content after the list product list, right?

Answer (score 8):

If you have child theme then override the catalog_category_view.xml. To override the xml file follow the below steps.

1. Copy the file from path **vendor/magento/mdoule-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**
2. paste it into the path **app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**
3. add the code below body tag

   ```
   <move element="category.cms" destination ="content" after="category.product"/>
   ```
4. If you do not have child theme. Then you will have to create child from the given link below and repeat step from 1 to 3
   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Comment: This is great. When you have 2 elements, with the same destination and positioning for "after". How do you set the priority order? We have a category, where we want the static block to appear above the category description for example.

Answer (score 0):

Go to product view phtml  file and call your static block where you want to call

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock(‘Magento\Cms\Block\Block’)->setBlockId(‘block_identifier’)->toHtml();?>
```