# Add static block after products on each subcategory

Tags: magento, magento2

I wanna add a static block after product list on each subcategory.

The static block couldn't be the same in all subcategories, i need that each subcategory have different information inside that block.

Ex:

- Shoes -> Static Block says: Buy our best shoes.
- T-Shirt -> Static Block says: Buy our best T-shirt.

I know that i can add description to that subcategory but i need the static block after the product list.

Any solution?

Comment: You can assign cms block to categories from the admin and select the display setting as Block and Products. Magento has this inbuilt by default.

Comment: @AnkurGoyal thanks for answer. But how can i move that block to the bottom? First the products and after of that, the block.

Comment: I solved it, if someone have the same issue can see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47699524/how-to-move-static-block-in-magento-2-1-8-at-the-bottom-of-product-list-in-categ